# AngularJS directive: append and update html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where i need also to append child element on update, what i have done is this:

```
var el = $compile('<a href="http://' + image.url + '">' + image.name + '</a>')( scope );
element.append(el);
```

This works, but on update it will always append new link tag without removing the previous one, how can i remove the existing and add new one?
Or there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Post your directive code as well so that what you are trying to do is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call element.empty() before element.append()

but i would recommend using [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) directive.

```
<a ng-href="http://{{image.url}}">{{image.name}}</a>
```